# How to test Responsive Web Design on XAMPP?

Tags: php, testing, responsive-design, xampp, device

Does anyone know if there is a way to test responsive web design on a local development environment such as XAMPP? I've bought a couple of responsive themes and have set them up locally on XAMPP but I haven't found a way to test it and ensure they work on all devices.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just resizing your browser?

Comment: How to resize the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these sites to test your design. These sites will allow you to resize your browser according the specific devices sizes and will let you navigate your site in it.

1. http://www.responsinator.com/
2. http://resizemybrowser.com/
3. http://www.jamus.co.uk/demos/rwd-demonstrations/
4. http://codebomber.com/jquery/resizer/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried responsinator, however that is if the theme/files are uploaded to a web. Do you know of any solutions I can use to test on local machines?

Comment: You can use the same, just put your local address, for example: http://localhost/path-to-your-file.php

Answer (score 3):

frietkot was right. Here is what I did on a mac:

- install the Resizer extension in Chrome
- start MAMP
- fire up chrome, open my local page (localhost:8888/the-path-to-your-page)
- clicked on the Resizer extension icon

Et voilà !

Might sound silly but I was also struggling to find an easy way to test for responsive design locally so I hope this will help someone. Of course it is limited to Chrome, but that's a start!

Answer (score 1):

There is a viewport resizing tool called [ish](http://bradfrostweb.com/demo/ish/). You can find it on gitHub [here](https://github.com/bradfrost/ish.). Download it and put the extracted folder in your localhost/htdocs. Then call it from your browser (eg localhost/ish). In the url box (top-left of the page) put the url to the site on your localhost you want to check.

ish. is yet another viewport resizing tool. It’s called “ish.” because it focuses on general ranges (small-ish. medium-ish. large-ish.), rather than popular device widths.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing your browser. If your site changes, it's responsive.

If you want to test it on mobile devices (such as an phone or tablet). You'll have to upload it to a server or setup a local server with internet access (maybe it'll work with just the 192.168.1.1 ip address in your mobile browser).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little tool to test responsivity, specifically designed to test Bootstrap breakpoints:

http://deneskellner.com/reframe

Enjoy :)